Jenkins Docker Error: Failed to run image the working directory is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path
Running Windows 11 with Docker in WSL
I'm learning CICD Jenkins and I'm the book section where I use Jenkins and Docker. treat me like I know nothing about docker. I'm facing this issue where the Jenkins Docker plugin is buggy: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60473
And since this plugin is no longer maintained. I would like your help getting this jenkins script to run:
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Code Checkout") {
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: 'C:\\Users\\path\\own\\CI-CD-Pipeline-with-Docker-and-Jenkins-main'
            }
        }
        stage("Code Stability | Build Image") {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.build("name_of_docker_image/spring3hibernate:${env.BUILD_ID}")
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Code Quality | Checkstyle | Hadolint") {
            parallel {
                stage("Checkstyle") {
                    agent {
                        docker { args "-v ${HOME}/.m2:/root/.m2" image "opstreedevops/maven:java8"}
                        }
                    steps {
                        git branch: 'main', url: 'C:\\Users\\path\\own\\CI-CD-Pipeline-with-Docker-and-Jenkins-main'
                        bat "mvn checkstyle:checkstyle"
                        recordIssues sourceCodeRetention: 'LAST_BUILD', tools: [checkStyle(pattern: '**/checkstyle-result.xml')]
                    }
                }
                stage("Hadolint") {
                    steps {
                        bat "hadolint Dockerfile --no-fail -f json >> hadolint.json && type hadolint.json"
                        recordIssues sourceCodeRetention: 'LAST_BUILD', tools: [hadoLint(pattern: 'hadolint.json')]
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

the error I get is the same as in the issue listed above:
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'opstreedevops/maven:java8'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/CI/Spring3HibernateDocker@2/' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.

according to one of the ex-maintainer users should make docker commands directly and not use the Jenkins's docker global variable.
Anyone here that could help with this. I would like to finish this book.
Note: I will get to docker in the future.

I think the issue is with path format. As you are using WSL, docker requires absolute paths in a format it can understand, typically in Unix-style (e.g., /c/Users/...) rather than Windows-style (e.g., C:/Users/...).
Try with the below modified Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Code Checkout") {
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: 'file:///C:/Users/path/own/CI-CD-Pipeline-with-Docker-and-Jenkins-main'
            }
        }
        stage("Code Stability | Build Image") {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.build("name_of_docker_image/spring3hibernate:${env.BUILD_ID}")
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Code Quality | Checkstyle | Hadolint") {
            parallel {
                stage("Checkstyle") {
                    agent {
                        docker { 
                            image "opstreedevops/maven:java8"
                            args "-v /${HOME.replaceAll('\\\\', '/')}/.m2:/root/.m2"
                            workingDir "/workspace"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        bat "mvn checkstyle:checkstyle"
                        recordIssues sourceCodeRetention: 'LAST_BUILD', tools: [checkStyle(pattern: '**/checkstyle-result.xml')]
                    }
                }
                stage("Hadolint") {
                    steps {
                        bat "hadolint Dockerfile --no-fail -f json >> hadolint.json && type hadolint.json"
                        recordIssues sourceCodeRetention: 'LAST_BUILD', tools: [hadoLint(pattern: 'hadolint.json')]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

